# Hiding the Content tab from a user in Umbraco

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, umbraco, dashboard

I am looking into creating a custom app/tab in Umbraco, as an addition to the current ones (Content, Media etc..). The tab I am creating is called Articles and simply lists nodes of the article doctype (i will move onto filter this by logged in user).

I want to set it so that on logging in, a user will only see this tab for Articles, and not the others (content, media...).

I understand that I cannot simply un-check the Content tab in the users permissions as this would remove the users access to all the nodes and therefore they would not be able to browse any in this new tab.

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to simply hide this tab from the user?

For a bit of background..
Im trying to make a system whereby the content trees depend on the current user. So user 1 would only see their articles etc. Setting the start node in content is not enough as there are other nodes at different levels that the user should have access to. So I have decided to create a custom app/tab to grab all the nodes for the current user. In starting this I found that I cant simply remove the Content tab from their permissions, and that's led me to here. Any help/pointers with this would be great!

Comment: Simple answer - no you cannot "hide" tabs directly through umbraco. You can either see them or not. What would be the difference between hiding the content tab and not having it at all? .

Comment: If I completely remove the users access to the content tab, I can not show any nodes in any custom sections as the user will have no access to any content. So I need to keep the users access to content, but I dont want them viewing the content section, just my custom sections. I was hoping then, that I could simply hide this tab in the back office.

Comment: Hmm quite a tricky one here - I'm out of ideas. Have you tried looking or posting this question on the our.umbraco.org forum? Try there as I'm sure someone has done it before.

Comment: thanks for the help Filth, I've gone and posted the same question on the umbraco forums so I'll see if I get a response there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you had luck in the umbraco forums, but maybe you could avoid doing a complete custom section, just by doing some filtering in the standard content tree?

This can be achieved by using the events exposed by the BaseContentTree class. The last code example on this page shows an example of how to only show some pages to admin users in the content tree: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/using-applicationbase-to-register-events/event-examples

The advantage of filtering directly on this tree is, that the filtering will also take effect when using some of the content picker datatypes, that will let a user select other nodes form the content tree.

Comment: thanks for the link mortenbock! I think this may be the route I have to take. Someone mentioned a package (Epiphany Custom Content Tree) on the umbraco forums that could be the answer but I havent tried it yet. I'll give it a go and report back! Thanks!

Comment: The packaged mentioned above worked for me. It doesn't hide the content tab as I wanted, but allowed me to specify multiple start nodes. I can achieve the effect that I wanted, but rather than having the content section called "Articles" its still the standard "Content". As far as I can tell, this package provides a config approach to filtering the standard content tree. As you suggested this approach over the extra section, I've marked your answer as accepted. Cheers.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that package is actually using this exact approach, just in a configurable manner, so that makes perfect sense.